# Can't change text of textView dynamically when using ViewPager and Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview, android-viewpager

I'm simply trying to change the text of a textView that is located within the actual fragment. It isn't throwing any error but it simply isn't updating. Aside from this the fragment successfully attaches to the activity via a viewpager.

The fragment:

```
public class FragmentPlotData extends Fragment {
    public static TextView textViewPlotData;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plot_data, container, false);
        textViewPlotData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPlotData);
        textViewPlotData.setText("Changed text ");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plot_data, container, false);
    }
}
```

The fragment's layout:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlotData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black_process_2"
        android:text="@string/original text"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return `view` in `onCreateView`, don't inflate a new layout like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plot_data, container, false);
```

to:

```
return view;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. @user3290180